# 301 response with 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked' despite having correct CORS headers configured

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors, http-status-code-301

I'm accessing nasa pictures with their public api, but i get this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at
[nasa api website] (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

But when i inspect their response header, the ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is present and set to '*', here you can see it:

**RESPONSE HEADERS:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Age 0
Cache-Control   max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Date    Sat, 28 Mar 2020 14:37:13 GMT
Etag    W/"e26hidden..."
Referrer-Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Server  openresty
Strict-Transport-Security   max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Vary    Origin
Via https/1.1 api-umbrella (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ]), 1.1 vegur
X-Cache MISS
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
X-Download-Options  noopen
X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies   none
X-RateLimit-Limit   1000
X-RateLimit-Remaining   999
X-Request-Id    00c8c415-37ad-474b-bfbd-8e968d60f37f
X-Runtime   0.125778
X-Xss-Protection    1; mode=block
```

**REQUEST HEADERS:**

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Host    api.nasa.gov
If-None-Match   W/"e26chidden.."
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests   1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:74.0) Gecko/999991 Firefox/74.0
```

Comment: You have "Response Headers" in there twice, shouldn't one be the "Request Headers"?

Comment: How are is your javascript requesting the data?

Comment: Use the Network pane in browser devtools to inspect all the requests the browser is sending and all the responses the browser is receiving. Check the HTTP status code of the response. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: Yes, the second response header is actually request headers, i edited it.
The js request is `req.open("GET", myUrl);
req.send();`
The call to the api goes fine, but then i try to copy the img in canvas and it gives me cors errors, the status code is 301:
`Request URL:http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/01000/opgs/edr/ncam/NLB_486272784EDR_F0481570NCAM00415M_.JPG
Request Method:GET
Remote Address:54.183.32.82:80
Status Code:
301
Version:HTTP/1.1`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There’s a common mistake that can happen when specifying a URL for a cross-origin request in code, and the mistake can cause browsers to end up reporting a CORS error when in fact the problem is simply an easy-to-overlook mistake in the request URL itself.

The mistake is just a missing `"s"`: using `"http"` as the URL protocol part instead of `"https"`.

That missing `"s"`  causes the server you sent the request to respond with a 3xx redirect to the equivalent `https` location of that URL. But the problem is: by default, many/most servers won’t include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`  header in 3xx responses. So the browser gets that 3xx, but because it lacks the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`  header, the browser refuses to let your code  follow the redirect; instead the browser stops right there and emits a CORS error.

So when you encounter a case like this, the way to troubleshoot it is: Open the Network pane in  devtools and inspect the response. Check the response status code shown there and check the response headers. If the cause is the mistake described in this answer,  you’ll see a `Location` response header. That value is the URL to which the server is trying to redirect the request.

And when you look at the `Location` value, you might initially think it’s exactly the same as the request URL you have in your code, because it’s easy to overlook that the difference is just that single missing `"s"`. But of course if you take the URL in that `Location` value and replace the request URL in your frontend code with it, and it works, then the difference becomes apparent.

So in the case of the  URL in this question, the problem was just, the frontend code specified a `http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov` URL that should instead be a `https://mars.jpl.nasa.gov` URL.